# Как получить имя файла в котором работаешь?

Tags: php

Здраствуйте! Подскажите, могу ли я достать имя файла в котором работаю. Допустим, я работаю в файле `index.php`, как в коде мне достать его название? Но без `.php`, просто `index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Но без `.php`*

Используйте [basename()](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.basename.php), передавая расширение вторым параметром:

```
echo basename(__FILE__, '.php');
```

---

Но т.к. второй параметр *basename()* чувствителен к регистру, то лучше использовать [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php) c флагом *PATHINFO_FILENAME*:

```
echo pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```